# Babeljs finding files that don't exist

Tags: ember.js, babeljs

I am getting the following very confusing message when I run 'ember serve'

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "ember-blog/bower_components/moment/min/locales.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB"
```

It is also throwing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: ember-blog/bower_components/moment/templates/locale-header.js: Unexpected token (6:0)
  4 |    factory(global.moment)
  5 | }(this, function (moment) { 'use strict';
> 6 |
```

I used to have the moment package installed, but it has now been **deleted**. A check of the filesystem with ls -la reveals that there is no folder called 'moment', so **how is Babel finding a file?**

I tried deleting the files in the 'tmp' directory but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently it was reporting the file as being in `ember-blog/bower_components/moment/templates/locale-header.js`, but the file was actually in `ember-blog/app/bower_components/moment/templates/locale-header.js`.

Donno why it truncated the app part, but that's why I couldn't find the file that was causing me grief.